# Fit Lightbox container in window if image is larger

Tags: javascript, size, lightbox, css

I'm just looking for a simple way to set the max width and height of the Lightbox container and image based on the window size **if the image is larger than the current window size.**

So say the image is 2000x1200 and the window is 1280x1024, then the `max-height` and `max-width` of `div.lb-outerContainer` and `img.lb-image` should be set to

```
$(window).height() - 286, $(window).width() - 60
```

and

```
$(window).height() - 306, $(window).width() - 80
```

respectively.

I'm just having a bit of trouble determining where to go about implementing these rules. Do I do it in the `lightbox.js` file? If so, where? Would it be acceptable to just throw in some script on the page it's used on?

Answer (score 0):

This answer isn't for lightbox only this is just general scaling of `.image` vs `window`

```
var $window = $(window),
    $image = $(".image");

$image.load(function() {
    var windowHeight = $window.height(),
        windowWidth = $window.width(),
        imageHeight = $image.height(),
        imageWidth = $image.width(),

        radioHeight = windowHeight/imageHeight,
        radioWidth;

        if ( radioHeight < 1 ) {
            imageHeight *= radioHeight;
            imageWidth *= radioHeight;
        }
        radioWidth = windowWidth/imageWidth;
        if ( radioWidth < 1 ) {
            imageHeight *= radioWidth;
            imageWidth *= radioWidth;
        }

    $image.height( imageHeight );
    $image.width( imageWidth );
});
```

And demo: http://jsbin.com/upisen/1/edit

Answer (score 0):

This will not keep image ratio.
You have to use something like this :

```
$(function(){
$('SELECTOR FOR YOUR IMAGE').load(function() {
    this.removeAttribute( "height" );
    this.removeAttribute( "width" );
    this.style.height = this.style.width = "";
    $(this).data('w',this.width);
    $(this).data('h',this.height);
    ResizeGallery();
});
// on resize window 
$(window).resize(function() {
   ResizeGallery();
});
});


function ResizeGallery() {
    var img=$('SELECTOR FOR YOUR IMAGE');
    // remove attribute to get true size
    img.removeAttr( "height" );
    img.removeAttr( "width" );
    var w = img.data('w');
    var h = img.data('h'); 
    // compute maximum dimention
    var maxW = $(window).width()-300; //300= margin
    var maxH = $(window).height()-200;
    // compute zoom ratio and keep only the smallest
    // also ratio must not exceed 1
    var ratio=Math.max(1,Math.min(maxW/w, maxH/h));
    // compute new dimentions
    var newW = Math.floor(ratio*w);
    var newH = Math.floor(ratio*h);

    // apply to image
    img.css('height',newW ).css('width',newH );
}
```

assuming you're using jquery

Comment: Right, I forgot to specify that the aspect ratio needs to be maintained, but I was hoping that was implied.

I should also have mentioned that all the images will be of a fixed width and that the gallery doesn't need to adapt when the window is re-sized, only when the Lightbox is opened.

I'll play around with it when I get into work tomorrow, but if in the meantime you feel like modifying your code to function when the Lightbox is opened rather than the window is re-sized, by all means.